# Inset does not work correctly. How to fix it?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

So I've got this thing and want to inset it

[image]

But if I inset, i get these artifacts:

[image]

So how do I fix this?

Comment: I guess you'll have to do it manually

Comment: @moonboots That's sad.

Comment: well, do you need so many edges?